# Laravel version 5.7 root show index of page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

Recently I am start using Laravel, and I develop a website in my local which works fine, but when I deploy it to a droplet in DigitalOcean, the root shows an index Of page.

[Screen Capture is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsDUa.png)

And when I navigate into the public folder, it shows a 500 error.

I have tried to include a few different .htaccess, which does not solve the problem. And my current .htaccess is below

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]

RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
```

The line "Options -MultiViews" is actually part of the .htaccess code too.

Could anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See more [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/why-do-my-laravel-routes-not-work)

In the server config file is the AllowOverride set to All or None? If its set to none all .htaccess changes will be ignored.

```
<Directory /var/www/YOURAPP/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: The server 500 error problem has been fixed, and there are a few more problems being fixed too after the 500 error.

However, currently I still encounter a strange problem.

When I visit the root of my domain, the browser show 403 forbidden message. But when I visit domain/public, it display the correct content, which mean there must be some setting I missed, but what should I change?

Comment: Can you edit the apache conf file? In that file there are some commented out code that you can edit like [this](https://imgur.com/a/U6OPJxB) but change the path to your app's path.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to generate a key...

```
php artisan key:generate
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation